# How do I update postgres table with a running total of amount

Tags: postgresql, cumsum

I am using Postgres. I can't UPDATE the table with a running total : "Cum_sum".

In the "cum_sum" column , I want to update the table with a permanent column, "Cum_sum". "Cum_sum" is a running total of Amount.

The select statement is a valid statement but I cannot update the table because UPDATE does not work with window functions.

Please assist.

```
SELECT cs3."Date",cs3."Amount",(sum("Amount") over (order by "Date")) as "Cum_sum" from cs3


cs3 Table
Date             Amount          Cum_sum
"2016-04-26"    "10.00000"  "10.00000"
"2016-06-01"    "-10.00000" "0.00000"
"2018-01-23"    "2150.57000"    "2150.57000"
"2018-01-30"    "-2150.57000"   "0.00000"
```

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: The select command works but this command doesn't UPDATE the table. I need the cs3 table updated to add further columns. When I submit further inquiries to the cs3 table. The "cum_sum" column is not there.

Comment: Does your table have a unique identifier column?  Is it the date column?

Comment: No. I will update the table with a unique primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [data-modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) here (assuming a newly added column `Balance`):

```sql
WITH balance (id, value) AS (
    SELECT id, (sum("Amount") over (order by "Date", id)) FROM cs3
)
UPDATE cs3 SET "Balance" = balance.value FROM balance WHERE cs3.id = balance.id;
```

Online example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=318929ea3bd4d029070558fe9b47f2a3

This is also why @Jeremy has asked for a primary key column as we need to make sure we're correlating the update values correctly.